# Why doesn't this GWT DialogBox center its two buttons?

Tags: java, gwt, dialog

I would expect setHorizontalAlignment to move my two buttons from the left over to the middle. Any idea why this is not working? All of the relevant code is below and pretty straightforward.

[image]

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final DialogBox deleteDialog = new DialogBox();
            deleteDialog.setModal(false);
            deleteDialog.setGlassEnabled(true);

            HorizontalPanel buttonPane = new HorizontalPanel();
            buttonPane.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);

            buttonPane.add(deleteDialogOKButton);
            buttonPane.add(deleteDialogCancelButton);

            deleteDialog.center();      

            deleteDialog.add(buttonPane);       
            deleteDialog.setText("Delete this Station?");

            deleteDialogOKButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    stationService.deleteStation(station, new DeleteStationCallback());
                    deleteDialog.hide();
                }});

            deleteDialogCancelButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    deleteDialog.hide();
                }});

            deleteDialog.show();
            //stationService.deleteStation(station, new DeleteStationCallback());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think HorizontalPanel has length here that equals 100%. Try to set align for inner widgets

Comment: You could try setting `buttonPane` to `margin: auto;` in css to center the buttonPane in the DialogBox.

Comment: In the code above, there is `HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT`. Did you try with `HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER`

Comment: Ganesh, yes I did. The align right was simply a test to see if I saw the elements shift to the right or move at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't give any width to your horizontal panel, it takes up the sum of the width of its contents. So `HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT`, `HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT` or any other alignment doesnot matter as its fitted in the given area. Try setting up the following,

```
buttonPane.setwidth(100%);
buttonPane.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTRE);
```

If this also doesn't work then you have to set cell alignment using the API

```
setCellHorizontalAlignment(Widget w,HasHorizontalAlignment.HorizontalAlignmentConstant align);
```

Comment: I've tried setting it to setWidth("100%"); to no luck. When I pair that with the second method for aligning center, it does somewhat center it, but there still seems to be excess space to the right of the second button. The final method you mentioned didn't help with this issue. 

Any idea why the first two would seemingly leave excess space to the right of the buttonPane?

Comment: It seems to be titled related. If I delete the set Title line, the dialog is only big enough to support the two buttons, properly centered.

Comment: According to me what I have mentioned should work.. I dunno what title line is to do with this

Comment: It does work, if there is no title text. Once I add in the text, the alignment goes wonky :(